# RVM install 1.9.2-head ERROR

Tags: ruby, git, https, installation, rvm

I am using RVM to maintain ROR enviroment:

But when I am trying to install ruby-head , it gives me error messages like this:

```
shanan@shanan-ThinkPad:~$ rvm install 1.9.2-head
/home/shanan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head, 
  this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.2-head - #fetching 
Cloning from https://github.com/ruby/ruby.git, this may take a while depending on your connection...
Cloning into /home/shanan/.rvm/repos/ruby-1.9.2-head...
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
cloning from https://github.com/ruby/ruby.git failed, now attempting to clone from https://github.com/ruby/ruby.git, this may take a while depending on your connection...
Cloning into /home/shanan/.rvm/repos/ruby-1.9.2-head...
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
There has been an error while trying to fetch the repository.               
Halting the installation.
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
shanan@shanan-ThinkPad:~$
```

**I am using git 1.7.4, and other dependencies are correctly installed and configured.
I really do not know why and how to solve this problem. Can you help me?**

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have installed following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
sudo apt-get install openssl
sudo apt-get install curl
```

The above are the dependencies of RVM

Once everything is done, just type `sudo rvm install 1.9.2`

I hope this will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

With rvm, [when it comes to installing](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/installing/), the documentation mentions:

> RVM maintains a list of interpreters and versions thereof to which it may install.
>   In order to see this list run the following command.

```
$ rvm list known
```

> Please note that RVM is not limited to simply this list.

Is there any way you can modify that list to take [an HTTP read-only](http://help.github.com/remotes/#clone) URL like `http://github.com/user/repo.git` ?

Because it seems some kind of `openssl` dependency might be missing (even though you did specify in your question that all dependencies are there)

[image: insanemy comic rvm illustration]

Comment: thanks man "rvm install 1.9.3-head" worked for me and I only saw it running the "rvm list known" command you suggested. RVM was supposed to make my life easier.... :'-(

Answer (score 0):

At the command-line enter `rvm notes` and make sure you have all the dependencies met.

It sounds like RVM can't find curl if it can't find a 'https' helper. If I remember right, git needs curl to do the heavy lifting.